# При вводе числа на первый вопрос получаю ошибку :NameError: name 'wozrast' is not defined

Tags: python

```
print("Привет! Это твой помощник")
print("Он сможет ответить на все твои вопросы")
print("Если хочешь задать вопрос, пиши)")
wopros1 = input()
    if wopros1 == "какое время суток сейчас?":
       print("Введите округлённое число!!!")
       wopros = int(input())
    if wopros <= 5 or wopros == 6:
       print('Доброй ночи!')
    elif wopros >= 7 and wopros <= 11:
         print('Доброе утро!')
    elif wopros >= 12 and wopros <= 17:
         print('Добрый день!')
    elif wopros >= 18 and wopros <= 22:
         print('Добрый вечер!')
    if wopros1 == "Расскажи сказку":
       print("Детскую или взрослую?")
       wozrast = input()
    if wozrast == "взрослую":
       print("Длинную или короткую?")
       skazka = input()
    if skazka == "Длинную":
       print("В этот лес завороженный,")
       print("По пушинкам серебра,")
       print("Я с винтовкой заряженной")
       print("На охоту шел вчера.")
       print("По дорожке чистой, гладкой")
       print("Я прошел, не наследил…")
       print("Кто ж катался здесь украдкой?")
       print("Кто здесь падал и ходил?")
       print("Подойду, взгляну поближе:")
       print("Хрупкий снег изломан весь.")
       print("Здесь вот когти, дальше — лыжи…")
       print("Кто-то странный бегал здесь.")
       print("Кабы твердо знал я тайну")
       print("Заколдованным речам,")
       print("Я узнал бы хоть случайно,")
       print("Кто здесь бродит по ночам.")
       print("Из-за елки бы высокой")
       print("Подсмотрел я на кругу:")
       print("Кто глубокий след далекий")
       print("Оставляет на снегу?..")
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что у вас проблемы с табуляцией (по крайней мере в коде, который вы написали здесь). Как я понимаю вас интересует именно этот кусок кода:

```
if wopros1 == "Расскажи сказку":
   print("Детскую или взрослую?")
   wozrast = input()
if wozrast == "взрослую":
   print("Длинную или короткую?")
   skazka = input()
if skazka == "Длинную":
   print("В этот лес завороженный,")
   #etc
```

У вас получается так, что вы в блоке `if wopros1 == "Расскажи сказку":` спрашиваете `wozrast`, а потом выходите из этого блока, а переменной продолжаете пользоваться. Как это должно выглядеть на самом деле:

```
if wopros1 == "Расскажи сказку":
   print("Детскую или взрослую?")
   wozrast = input()
   if wozrast == "взрослую":
       print("Длинную или короткую?")
       skazka = input()
   if skazka == "Длинную":
       print("В этот лес завороженный,")
   #etc
```

И хотелось бы дать ещё пару **советов** (если они вам не нужны, можете пропустить):

1. Вместо того, чтобы писать

```
print("Длинную или короткую?")
skazka = input()
```

можно написать:

```
skazka = input("Длинную или короткую?")
```

2. Не называйте переменные транслитом - плохой кодстайл. Лучше называть на английском языке, т.е. вместо `wopros` - `question` или `query`, вместо `skazka` - `tale`, вместо `wozrast` - `age`.
3. Зачем вы пишете

```
if wopros <= 5 or wopros == 6:
```

если можно:

```
if wopros <= 6:
```